# ASP.NET Webpage never loading - debug from VS (2015, 2017)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis-express

I have a very strange problem I'm fighting with since VS 2015 (maybe even 2013).
Now I'm working with VS 2017 and it still occurs.

Here is the situation.
I have a legacy web application (Webforms, later enhanced by integrating webapi REST with javascript/html client code, some WCF endpoints, etc).

I build and start debug session from within VS (I do debug/testing mostly with Chrome and FF, rarely with IE/Edge/etc.), and I use IIS Express.

Most of the time the application debug session starts just fine - the page loads in browser and I can either debug server side in VS / client side in browser's debug tools.

But sometimes, the page actually never completes loading, and no matter how long I wait, it just stays locked on "loading..." message.

The only solutions I found are:
- either restart PC
- or (in Chrome), start browser in new identity.
- switch to a different browser (e.g. after starting with Chrome, open page in FF - or vice-versa).

When the page loads normally, the VS's Output Debug window displays various tracing / debug messages or progress of loading various dlls.

[image: VS Output Debug when page loads and executes ok]

However, as soon as the problem described above starts to happen, the VS Output Debug starts to log msgs like

```
The thread <#nnnn> has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

[image: VS Output Debug when page no longer loads]

When this starts to happen, no matter what I do (except starting browser in new identity / change browser / restarting PC) I can no longer debug.
No matter if I totally close and restart the browser, clear cache, close and restart VS / IIS. Nothing helps.

The situation mentioned above occurs at very random intervals.
Sometimes I can work and debug for days (I suspend / hibernate the PC at the end of the day, resume next days, end everything works ok).
However other times the issue occur after just starting few debug sessions, and on occasions, even after a full shutdown / restart, at very first debug session, this happens.

I have lived with it for long time, but sometimes is very annoying.

Anyone have experienced a similar issue?
Any idea what is causing it, and is there is any fix / workaround?

Thank you

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzszcehe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

The messages in your output log reporting:

```
The thread <#nnnn> has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

Just indicates that the thread has exited safely and is very normal to see this in correctly working code.  In fact it would be abnormal to not see this as you will end up using all available threads.

From what you have explained I would suggest that you need to look at the extensions you have installed in your browsers.  I typically will use a vanilla profile (blank profile with no modifications / extensions) so that my debugging is not affected by any modifications the extensions can make.

I would also monitor your system's CPU and memory usage.  Are either of these being maxed out?